# How to get the purchase orders of a specific suppllier with domain filter

Tags: python, xml, odoo

I have a many2one field that gets  the purchase orders of the active supplier in the supplier's form view. For that, i've used a domain filter but it's not working. here is my code:

```
 _inherit='res.partner'  

BC=fields.Many2one('purchase.order', string='BC n°1', domain=lambda self: [("partner_id", "=", self.env['res.partner'].browse(self._context.get('active_id')))])
```

it's giving me the error "TypeError: res.partner() is not JSON serializable"
Any suggestions?

Comment: Or to say @Drako's comment in other words: please add some more information and try to describe your problem in a more understandable way.

Comment: Okey, i want to add a many2one field to the supplier's form view. This field has to give as choices the purchase orders related to the active supplier only. so I added a domain attribute in the many2one field in order to  satisfy the condition but it's giving me the error above.

Comment: The ``browse`` method returns a record, but domains work with IDs, so ``[("partner_id", "=", self._context.get('active_id'))]`` would be a more correct domain, but I'm really not sure about what ``active_id`` is when you're inside a model. Also, what you want is a One2many because you try to get purchase order**s** for **one** partner.

Comment: @Harlan , in fact , i don't want to get all the purchase orders for one partner as value of my field, but i want to have a selection which has the purchase orders of the current supplier only(not all the purchase orders), and then, we can choose "one" purchase order. That's why i've chosen Many2one field with domain filter.

Comment: the [("partner_id", "=", self._context.get('active_id'))] is not working neither!

Comment: Oh okay. So if you want to filter the available choices, you need to place your domain in the XML view : ``<field name='BC' domain='...'/>.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can define your domain using xml , it should be something like this :

```
  <field name="BC" domain="[('partner_id.id','=',id)]" />
```